# Finding how to calculate the speed of a magnetic train through a coil in a simple DIY Hyperloop model

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, speed

before I start, let me just say that I am terrible at physics, and this question might have some inaccurate vocabulary. I apologize for that.

I am currently working on a physics model (both theoretical and physical) of a simple DIY Hyperloop train, something similar to this video here: ([youtube](https://youtu.be/9k7zywli4Vg)). It uses magnets attached to both sides of a battery cell, placed into a copper coil, which allows it to zoom through the whole 'track'. Though, the thing is, my research revolves around the speed of the magnetic train through the whole track of copper coils, and whether attaching more magnets will affect it. The physical model is understandable (I think), but I'm flustered on the theoretical part of this research.

I must be able to create a prediction using formulas, equations, and whatnot, then compare such result with the physical model. However, Physics 2 was not my thing. I've been trying to understand how the magnetic field is induced just by placing the magnetic trains into the coil, and I'm still unsure about it to this day. The video explains that the north poles of both magnets will be facing towards the battery cell, and I don't know why that has to happen. Shouldn't that create some sort of repelling force in the middle of the magnetic train? Why would that result in the train travelling to only one side?

Then, in the next part, how are we able to derive a formula to get the speed of the magnetic train through the copper coil track? I'm not sure what formulas are related to this phenomenon, and if magnetic strength is even related to speed.

Again, I apologize for the lack of physics knowledge. I'm really hoping to get through this research project and learn something new. Thank you so much for reading.